# Script to calculate the product of numbers in all possible combinations

Tags: arrays, calculated-columns, date-arithmetic, cartesian-product

I have a db of numbers (percentages) which I want to calculate the product for each of the possible combinations of all the numbers and their difference from a 100%.

So for example, for the following numbers:
0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7

I want to calculate the following:

```
  (1-0.3)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)
  0.3*0.4*0.6*0.7
  0.3*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)
  (1-0.3)*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6)*0.7
  (1-0.3)*0.4*(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)
  (1-0.3)*(1-0.4)*0.6*(1-0.7)
  0.3*(1-0.4)*(1-0.6)*0.7
  0.3*(1-0.4)*0.6*(1-0.7)
  (1-0.3)*(1-0.4)*0.6*0.7
  (1-0.3)*0.4*(1-0.6)*0.7
  (1-0.3)*0.4*0.6*(1-0.7)
  0.3*0.4*(1-0.6)*(1-0.7)
  (1-0.3)*0.4*0.6*0.7
  0.3*(1-0.4)*0.6*0.7
  0.3*0.4*(1-0.6)*0.7
  0.3*0.4*0.6*(1-0.7)
```

I want to be able to build this for any n numbers (here I gave an example for 4 numbers, but there can be hundreds and thousands of these). How is it called? Is there a command for them? Is there a known script somewhere?
In the end I will need to sum them all up. And use them individually as well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a pre-defined command for this in any language, but most languages will allow you to write a recursive function for this. For example, in Haskell you could use:

```
calculate [] = [[]]
calculate (x:xs) = let rec = calculate xs
                       pos = map (x:) rec
                       neg = map ((1 - x):) rec
                   in pos ++ neg
```

You can try this out [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_haskell_online.php) and run your example with the line:

```
main = print (calculate [0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7])
```

Note that this `calculate` function takes a list of percentages as input and returns a list of lists, each of which represents a line in your desired result. This result can then be used to calculate your intermediate and final result.

The function works as follows. If your input is an empty list, return a list with an empty list. If the input has elements, separate the first element (`x`) from the remainder of the list (`xs`) and calculate the result on the remainder of the list. The result of this is a list with lists of percentages which is stored in `rec`.

To calculate the result value, prepend `x` to each list in `rec` (stored in `pos`) and prepend `1-x` to each list in `rec` (stored in `neg`). As the result we return one list which is the concatenation of `pos` and `neg`.